# Two lines intersect each other at integer coordinate

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

> For how many integers $m$, the lines $y=mx-1$ and $13x+11y=700$,
> intersect each other at an integer coordinates?
>
> $$1)\text{zero}\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad 
>  2)1\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad3)2\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad4)4\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad5)\text{infinity}$$

First I tried to solve the system of equations:

From the first equation we have $11y=11mx-11$,  plugging it in the other equation to get

$(11m+13)x=711$ therefore $x=\cfrac{3^2\times79}{11m+13}$. if we plug it in the first equation we have $y=\cfrac{711m}{11m+13}-1$. we need these two fractions be integer numbers. I don't know how to continue.

Comment: You know $11m+13$ has to be a divisor of 711, but you know all the divisors of 711.

Comment: @user10354138 It has $6$ divisor so I get six values for $m$. then should I put each values in the equations of $y$ to check it is integer or not? is there any shortcut for that?

Comment: It has 12 divisors of the form $\pm 3^a\cdot 79^b$, not all of which gives you integer $m$.

Comment: Oh you are right, I missed negative ones.

Comment: I think that the answer is $1$ because the only integer (I've found) is $m=6$